# combining loc code lines into 1 function python pandas

Tags: pandas, function, rename, pandas-loc

I have some code which cleans up browser names to short names in a pandas dataframe column e.g. 'Edge 12345678' becomes 'Edge'.

Because I want to account for future versions of browsers (the version number will change) I haven't used a dictionary. I have used the pandas loc function to identify the first two letters of the browser name field and then replace it with the short name (in a new column).

this code works:

```
df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ch', 'Browser_type'] = 'Chrome'
df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Mo', 'Browser_type'] = 'Mozilla'
df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Ed', 'Browser_type'] = 'Edge'
df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == 'Fi', 'Browser_type'] = 'Firefox'

df.head()
```

But I am trying to write a function to do this now and would like to write it as one line.

like this:

```
df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == ['Ch'|'Mo'|'Ed'|'Fi'], 'Browser_type'] = ['Chrome'|'Mozilla'|'Edge'|'Firefox']
df.head(3)
```

but I get this error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0f4153661736> in <module>
      1 df = pd.read_csv ('dummy_webchat_data.csv')
----> 2 df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == ['Ch'|'Mo'|'Ed'|'Fi'], 'Browser_type'] = ['Chrome'|'Mozilla'|'Edge'|'Firefox']
      3 df.head(3)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

If I use comma instead of '|' I get:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5ddc9867daf5> in <module>
      1 df = pd.read_csv ('dummy_webchat_data.csv')
----> 2 df.loc[df['Browser'].str[:2] == ['Ch','Mo','Ed','Fi'], 'Browser_type'] = ['Chrome','Mozilla','Edge','Firefox']
      3 df.head(3)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    527         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True)
    528 
--> 529         res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    530 
    531         return _construct_result(self, res_values, index=self.index, name=res_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    232         #  The ambiguous case is object-dtype.  See GH#27803
    233         if len(lvalues) != len(rvalues):
--> 234             raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
    235 
    236     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Please could someone help me write this more efficiently using loc?

thank you

M

Answer (score 1):

Try Numpy for one liner

```
import numpy as np

# df['column_name'] = np.select(conditions, values)
df['Browzer_type'] = np.select([(df['A'] == 'Chro'), (df['Browzer'] == 'Mozi'), (df['A'] == 'Ed'), (df['A'] == 'Fir')], ['Chrome', 'Mozilla', 'Edge', 'Firefox'])
```

Comment: I thought it had worked but when I looked closer the new column was populated by 0's. I think this is because the code is looking for the exact string (e.g. 'Chro' rather than the first few letters as per my original code @Raghav Sharma